# How to Send Authentication Token Header with DropzoneJs?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am having a problem sending an authorization header with [dropzonejs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-withCredentials)

```
  this.componentConfig = {
      iconFiletypes: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif'],
      showFiletypeIcon: true,
      postUrl: `${getBaseUrl()}/Controller/ImportImage`,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer'
      },
    };


  <DropzoneComponent config={config} eventHandlers={eventHandlers} djsConfig={djsConfig}> </DropzoneComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the code](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/dist/dropzone.js) the headers are define like:

```
var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
  };
```

So, defining like

```
headers: { "Authorization" : "Bearer AbCdEf123456" }
```

should work.